# When can children understand the concept of lying?

Tags: development

How old does a child have to be to be lying on purpose?  How old are they before they can understand the concept of a lie vs the truth?  What about not the truth vs the truth?

Comment: Is there a difference between 'lie' and 'not the truth'? As for an answer, I'm guessing that this is like most developmental stages and likely has quite a variance in age ranges.

Comment: @DA01: Truth: telling what happened. Lie: Telling something else than what happened. Not truth: diversion, not revealing anything at all, etc.: it's not a lie if you evade the topic.

Comment: "it's not a lie if you evade the topic" oh! Politics! ;)

Comment: This [documentary film](http://www.videoportal.sf.tv/video?id=84d1dd30-8aa8-4db1-aecc-080e58299573) (german) says that children above the age of 4 years are able to lie on purpose. The ability to put oneself in the position of someone else in order to foresee how the lie effects the other person is a requirement for lying, they say.

Comment: Some people say that if you are asked a direct question and you do not tell them what they are asking for, that falls within the realm of 'lying' for them. If the truth needs to come out and you impede it, it is culpable, no matter what word you use. That said, you need not help people do wrong.

Answer (score 7):

A few additional thoughts to @monsto's answer:

Roughly till the age of 7 (+-3), children live in a *magical* world, which is very different from how we adults experience (or seem to experience) things. Their world is shaped by their own thoughts, desires, images much more than by some solid "objective", "external" reality. Very often, they are *confabulating* this world and its events, rather than *describing* as we would expect. Just recently, during the holiday season, my younger daughter told us that she saw an elf peering through the window, and they both hailed each other. Was she making up a story? Yes. Was she lying? Absolutely not.

OK, you might say, this is a cute little story. Let's see another one. Jim notices that someone took money from his coat pocket, and they find out it was his elder son Joe (8). They actually find the missing money in Joe's bag. When asked "did you take Dad's money?", Joe says no. Is he lying? By adult categories, yes. However, by child categories, it is a very different story. Joe recently got a little sister, Sarah. Naturally, a lot of attention and energy in the family is now shifted from him to Sarah, which is very frustrating to him. Stealing is a (misguided) attempt to get more attention and care from his dad. When confronted with the question, he wishes he had never done it, and expresses this wish by saying "no".

Bottom line is, it is often too easy and tempting to apply adult terms and categories to what children do and say, and act out of these classifications. However, children aren't little adults. Without actually understanding (or rather, feeling into) their situation and motives, it is dangerous to judge (much less to punish) them. Moreover, since the pace of personal development is extremely varied between individual children, 3 children of the same biological age can be on very different cognitive / emotional / social levels.

Comment: Torok I would never ask a child if he/she lied.  You know they are lying and to ask them if they did is only asking for another lie.  As well, in this example it is obvious why he lied so why make him explain it, simple tell him he shouldn't lie and then do some appropriate disciplinary action prior to giving him extra hugs, kisses, and play time.

Comment: @morahhochman, this sounds like my answer implied to you that any of the children in these stories were asked if they lied, or that I meant to encourage readers to do so. What made you think I did?

Comment: I still live in a magical world.

Answer (score 5):

I found a good article on [telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/science-news/3298979/Babies-not-as-innocent-as-they-pretend.html) that answers this question.  But first, what counts as "lying"?  The studies mentioned in the article are pretty broad, and include any sort of intentional deception.  Taking that definition, **babies can  lie as early as 6 to 8 months!**

> Infants quickly learnt that using tactics such as fake crying and pretend laughing could win them attention. By eight months, more difficult deceptions became apparent, such as concealing forbidden activities or trying to distract parents' attention.

It goes on to say that later, when kids are around 2-year-olds, their lies can become more sophisticated.  They'll say "I don't care" when threatened with punishment, even if they do care.

Comment: Its enough to make you believe in Original Sin : )

Answer (score 5):

When I was in college, back in the 80s, I wrote a paper for some psych class on truth and lies. In it, I came to the conclusion that there's several different types of truth and lie. for convenience, I classified them in shades of grey.

When faced with the question "did you take my money?" and the person actually did take the money...

- white truth: "Yes."
- black truth: "Yes, but i thought it was mine."
- white lie: "No, but what if I needed it?"
- black lie: "No."

and several variations in between that I won't go into. The point i'm trying to make is that there's a lot more to truths and falsities than people care to admit (lest they reveal the intentions at the core of their personality). It takes quite a while before a kid can understand the subtleties of interpersonal relationships, let alone actively attempt to manipulate them.

Fake laugh and cry are not about deception (a pretty advanced concept) and all about self-advantage. In other words, they're not trying to get you to give up something you value, they're just trying to get something for themselves. Any child up to about 4 is going to act that way. Deception involves clear comprehension of the other person's point of view. It's actively attempting to thwart the other persons defenses, in many cases so that they give up something that has value. I'm no psychologist, but i'll bet that's not something you'll see till minimum 8 or 9.

So lets say a 3 yo playdate. Finn starts crying and throws a brick (megablock) at the other kid.

```
"Finn, why did you throw the brick at Marceline?"
"She took my goldfish!"
"Marceline, did you take his goldfish?"
"No, I didn't have any!"
```

If Finn and Marceline were 13, we would assume that she was lying to stay out of trouble. a 3 yo Marceline just wanted more goldfish, probably took the last 3 out of Finns cup *without realizing* (dare i say without caring) that they belonged to someone else. A common interaction that has ZERO to do with lying. It's all about property. And hunger.

Punishment? Nah. establish the boundaries "this is your cup, marceline. THAT one is finns" and give em a few more goldfish and this crisis is averted. Of course, if it continues, marceline needs to be dealt with, but that's a different topic.

toddlers generally don't understand the interpersonal dynamics that are the foundation to lying. even bad bad toddlers that hide stuff aren't being deceptive, it's all about something they want... even if a 4yo is constantly hiding daddy's cigarettes. they really just want more attention from daddy.

Bottom line: what do you do? when you hear hooves, think horses not zebras. The solution to the problem is a simple one based on the childs personality, not the adults sensibilities.

Comment: Deception in all varieties is just a way to fill a need.

Comment: How many shades of grey did you come up with? Fifty? Thank you for the description of how deception involves manipulation, while simple lying could just be self-centered.